# Firebase Cloud Messaging in Angular doesn't receive data messages

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've implemented a Firebase Cloud Messaging in Angular as [this tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/send-push-notifications-in-angular-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/).

I can receive "normal" push notifications from my server. But I can't receive data messages (messages without 'notification' key in json, as you can check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)).

Message example:

```
{
   "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
   "data" : {
       "Nick" : "Mario",
       "body" : "great match!",
       "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
   },
 }
```

Function to receive messages:

```
receiveMessage() {
    this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
        console.log("Message received. ", payload);
        this.currentMessage.next(payload);
    });
}
```

The messages with notification key are received correctly.

I need that kind of messages to sync my app, I don't want to display them.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. Were you able to fix this?

Comment: I didn't solve it. I'm trying to use a different approach to sync my application. I'm using a socket.